# Angular 7: How to access query string in URL from an iframe?

Tags: angular, angular7, query-string, angular-cli-v7

The app under development is hosted within an iframe.

I have the following routes configured in my app:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'list'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ListComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateRoute]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In the `ListComponent`, `OnInit` method, I have used the following code to get query string params:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        console.log("val.state.root.firstChild.params: " + val.state.root.firstChild.params);
      }
    }); 
const firstParam: string = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id');
```

None of these seem to work.
The url I have for my application is as follows:

*https://company.com/#/app-dev/list?id=3*

`QueryParamMap` or `RoutesRecongnized` doesn't seem to get the query string "id=3" in the url. It always returns null.

Can anyone help me how to retrieve the query params / query string from url in angular app?

Comment: Did you add the parameters to the iFrame url or to the host url? If you didn't try passing the parameters to the iFrame.

Comment: What is the full iframe URL for your application?

Answer (score 0):

As the app is under iframe . Rather then going for snapshot you should use 
   subscribe method to fetch the params .Also check if the **fragment** gets you 
   full url after #

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe to **queryParams** instead of params. See reference https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html

Answer (score 0):

This may help you somewhat

```
const firstParam: string = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of snapshot, you need to read via Subscriptions or use Rxjs

Below is the example:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
            //you will get query string here
        });
    });
}
```

Go through the link for Rxjs implementation. Link: https://kamranahmed.info/blog/2018/02/28/dealing-with-route-params-in-angular-5/